# Organising numbers into new array, while-loop issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I want to organise the numbers (including duplicates) from randomNumbers in order from highest to lowest & insert them into organisedNumbers.

I think it is my while loop throwing it off but I don't understand why.

```js
let randomNumbers = [9, 2, 6, 8, 52, 56, 7, 43, 56, 31, 48, 3, 6, 8, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 17, 25];
let organisedNumbers = [];

function unjumbleTwo(sourceArray, resultArray) {
  for (let i = 0, next = false; i < Math.max(...sourceArray); next === true) {
    next = false;
    let temp = sourceArray[sourceArray.indexOf(i)];
    while (typeof temp === 'number') {
      resultArray.push(temp);
    }
    next = true;
  }
};
unjumbleTwo(randomNumbers, organisedNumbers);
console.log(organisedNumbers);
```

Edit: 'i' never changed. Fixed and got rid of 'next === true, false'.

```
function unjumble(sourceArray,resultArray){
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(...sourceArray); i++){
    let temp = sourceArray[sourceArray.indexOf(i)];
    while (typeof temp === 'number'){
      resultArray.push(temp);
    }
  }
};
unjumble(randomNumbers,organisedNumbers);
console.log(organisedNumbers);
```

Comment: Hey, why are you doing it manually ? There's library or native methods to do this. take a look on sort() method

Comment: I think the for-loop is misused. `next === true` seems weird to me

Comment: where are you changing the i?

Comment: `const organisedNumbers =  [9, 2, 6, 8, 52, 56, 7, 43, 56, 31, 48, 3, 6, 8, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 17, 25].slice(0).sort((a,b) => a-b);
console.log(organisedNumbers);`

Comment: And yes, you never get a new temp inside the while loop and never stop

Comment: PS: a-b for ascending, b-a for descending

Answer (score -1):

Just return it like this:

`randomNumbers.sort((a,b) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0);`

Comment: 1. HUGE duplicate. 2. You mutate the original

Answer (score -1):

You can use sort function:

```
let randomNumbers = [9,2,6,8,52,56,7,43,56,31,48,3,6,8,4,1,3,4,5,17,25];
let organisedNumbers = randomNumbers.sort((a, b) => b - a);

console.log(organisedNumbers)
```

Comment: 1. Huge dupe and 2. You mutate the original. Sort works in situ